# Creating new list from 2 existing lists, where their values match

Tags: python, list

I would like to do that in the screenshot. Could you please help me on that?

Code:

```
import numpy as np

op = np.array([[46, 29],
               [39, 47],
               [25, 47],
               [31, 24]])
rt = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 0],  # op[0][1]+op[1][1]+op[2][1]+op[3][0]= 29 + 47 + 47 + 31 = 154
               [1, 0, 1, 1],
               [1, 0, 1, 0],
               [0, 1, 0, 1],
               [1, 1, 0, 0],
               [0, 1, 1, 1],
               [0, 1, 0, 1],
               [1, 1, 1, 0],
               [0, 1, 1, 0],
               [1, 0, 1, 0]])
```

[image]

Comment: Your code should be in the question so people can copy/paste it into their IDE/terminal. I'd suggest re-writing your question

Comment: Thank you, I am new here. I will be careful next time.

Comment: it will result in you getting better/more help. It’s just a tip for when you’re asking questions

Answer (score 0):

This is a pure Python solution.  There may be a more performant NumPy solution.  Here we iterate through, `rt` and zip the subarrays there with `op`.  Then we use the values of the `rt` subarrays as indices in the `op` subarrays, and sum the values we look up.

```
[sum(o[r] for o, r in zip(op, x)) for x in rt]
# [154, 139, 146, 142, 132, 164, 142, 154, 171, 146]
```

Answer (score -1):

What you're doing looks very much like matrix multiplication. Numpy has a matmul operation that will do what you want for you.

```
np.matmul(rt, op)
```